# postgresql top value multiple join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Lets say i have this dummy table

```
CREATE TABLE dim_product (
    product_id int4 null primary key,
    product_name varchar(100) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dim_territory (
    territory_id int4 null primary key,
    region varchar(30) NULL
);    
CREATE TABLE fact_sales (
    order_detail_id varchar(30) null primary key,
    product_id int4 NULL,
    territory_id int4 NULL,
    quantity int4 NULL,
    foreign key(product_id) references dim_product(product_id),
    foreign key(territory_id) references dim_territory(territory_id)
);

insert into dim_product 
(product_id, product_name)
values
(1, 'patch kit'), 
(2, 'mountain bike'), 
(3, 'logo');        
insert into dim_territory 
(territory_id, region)
values
(1, 'AUS'),
(2, 'FRN'),
(3, 'GRMN');    
insert into fact_sales
(order_detail_id, product_id, territory_id, quantity)
values
('z1', 1, 1, 1),
('z2', 1, 1, 3),
('z3', 2, 1, 4),
('z4', 3, 2, 4),
('z5', 3, 2, 2),
('y1', 2, 1, 1),
('y2', 1, 3, 4),
('y3', 2, 3, 5),
('x4', 3, 3, 1),
('x5', 3, 2, 4);
```

I want to know top 2 product in each region based on quantity

I've tried with this code, but it make me confused lol :D

```
select DT.region, DP.product_name, sum(FS.quantity) as quantity
from fact_sales FS 
     join dim_territory DT
     on FS.territory_id=DT.territory_id
     join dim_product DP
     on FS.territory_id=DT.territory_id
group by product_name, region
order by quantity desc
```

the outcome of that code is like this, this is so wrong

region     product_name    quantity
GRMN       patch kit       10
FRN        logo            10
GRMN       logo            10
FRN        mountain bike   10
GRMN       mountain bike   10
FRN        patch kit       10
AUS        mountain bike   9
AUS        patch kit       9
AUS        logo            9

how to I fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at window functions, specially at `rank()`, `dense_rank()` and `row_number()`, e.g.

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER w AS rank
FROM (
  SELECT DT.region, DP.product_name, sum(FS.quantity) AS quantity
  FROM fact_sales FS 
  JOIN dim_territory DT ON FS.territory_id=DT.territory_id
  JOIN dim_product DP ON FS.product_id=DP.product_id
  GROUP BY product_name, region
) j 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY quantity DESC
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

If you wish to filter out the lower ranked rows, put it in a CTE (or another subquery) and constrain the results to the rank you want:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER w AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT DT.region, DP.product_name, sum(FS.quantity) AS quantity
    FROM fact_sales FS 
    JOIN dim_territory DT ON FS.territory_id=DT.territory_id
    JOIN dim_product DP ON FS.product_id=DP.product_id
    GROUP BY product_name, region
  ) i 
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY quantity DESC
               RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
)
SELECT * FROM j WHERE rank <= 2;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=11080eb055e4503bc481eb54467f171a)

Comment: @Napier btw, your fiddle is empty :)

Comment: @Napier https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=11080eb055e4503bc481eb54467f171a

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on the second join with the variables you are using.

Try this:

```
    select DT.region, DP.product_name, sum(FS.quantity) as quantity
from fact_sales FS 
     join dim_territory DT
     on FS.territory_id=DT.territory_id
     join dim_product DP
     on FS.product_id=DP.product_id
group by product_name, region
order by quantity desc
```